# Make pygame/SDL installer for mac

Tags: python, macos, sdl, pygame

I have a customized version of SDL 1.2 and pygame 1.9.1 that implement SDL2's high precision timer and event time-stamping. I can build everything fine on my mac, but I'd like to be able to distribute an installer to my colleagues who are less computationally savvy. The pygame downloads page has installers available, so presumably this is possible. Any suggestions as to how to go about this or where to go for some instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into the Python standard librariy [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html). With it you can create setup scripts to build and package your code, even with C extensions.

If this doesn't suffice you, you can also look into [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) which basically extends distutils and even allows you to upload your code to the [Python Package Index (PyPi)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) from where you can easily download and install python packages.

**EDIT**

Sorry for being so vague, but the implementation of your setup script (usually *setup.py*) is mainly depending on your actual requirements.

**EDIT 2**

To create mpkg packages you require setuptools and another library called [Bento](http://cournape.github.com/Bento/). After you have written your `setup.py` script (look at the [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) docs for that) you can build it with:

```
python setup.py build_mpkg
```

Comment: I was hoping to create a mpkg like how those available on the pygame downloads, which would include SDL as a framework (plus SDL_image, SDL_mixer, etc) and put it in its proper place (/Library/Frameworks) during the install process. Can the packages you mention achieve this?

Comment: No, as far as I know this is not possible, for this to work you'd need another library called *Bento* (http://cournape.github.com/Bento/). Use the command line option `build_mpkg` on your `setup.py` script to create the package.